# Cycles render HDRI lighted object on a 2d background image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

I am currently attempting to render a picture with a regular 2D picture (not as a plane), composited onto a HDRI lit object. How can I render where the 2D picture is output, and the HDRI only for lighting?

Thank you for reading

Comment: can you draw [by hand] what it would look like?